# handle SMS- onReceive to trigger event in another activity/class

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

so, what i'm trying to do is change some ui elements which are expanded in my main activity- and i want the changes to be triggered by the onReceive, which is from broadcastreceiver extended in a different separate class.

I'd like to do something like this

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(context, intent){

MainActivity main = new MainActivity();   //this is my... main activity :)

main.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.green);
}//end onReceive

}//end class
```

in my MainActivity, i've set values to the GUI button element like this:

```
public class mainactivity extends activity... implements onclick... bla bla (){
Button button;

onCreate....{
  button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

so i'd like to know if when onReceive is activated, can i edit the state of a widget in ANOTHER activity by instantiating that activity and calling a setter method on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will not work because you are creating a new instance of MainActivity. This will not reference your currently active main activity. One solution you may try is sending another intent to your activity and implementing [onNewIntent(Intent newIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) in your activity. That way you can update your main activity in that function, try passing extras in with the new information you have received.